# What is used to train a self-attention mechanism?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, attention-model

I've been trying to understand self-attention, but everything I found doesn't explain the concept on a high level very well.

Let's say we use self-attention in a NLP task, so our input is a sentence.

Then self-attention can be used to measure how "important" each word in the sentence is for every other word.

The problem is that I do not understand how that "importance" is measured. Important for what?

What exactly is the goal vector the weights in the self-attention algorithm are trained against?

Comment: I found this resource quite understandable: https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-self-attention-2d627e33b20a

Answer (score 0):

Connecting language with underlying meaning is called grounding. A sentence like “The ball is on the table” results into an image which can be reproduced with multimodal learning. Multimodal means, that different kind of words are available for example events, action words, subjects and so on. A self-attention mechanism works with mapping input vector to output vectors and between them is a neural network. The output vector of the neural network is referencing to the grounded situation.

Let us make a short example. We need a pixel image which is 300x200, we need a sentence in natural language and we need a parser. The parser works in both directions. He can convert text to image, that means the sentence “The ball is on the table” gets converted into the 300x200 image. But it is also possible to parse a given image and extract the natural sentence back. Self-attention learning is a bootstrapping technique to learn and use the grounded relationship. That means to verify existing language models, to learn new one and to predict future system states.

Comment: >The output vector of the neural network is referencing to the grounded situation.                                                                                              So the output vector varies from task to task. I've been suspecting that, but it isn't made clear anywhere i saw

Comment: Multimodal doesn't mean that unfortunately. Multimodal means multiple modalities that are inherently differently constructed types of information - text, image, audio

Answer (score 0):

This question is old now but I came across it so I figured I should update others as my own understanding has increased.

Attention simply refers to some operation that takes the output and combines it with some other information.  Typically this just happens by taking the dot product of the output with some other vector so it can "attend" to it in some way.

Self-attention combines the output with other parts of the input (hence self part).  Again the combination usually occurs via the dot-product between the vectors.

Finally how is attention (or self-attention) trained?
Let's call Z our output, W our weight matrix and X our input (we'll use @ as matrix multiplication symbol).

```
Z = X^T @ W^T @ X
```

In NLP we will compare Z to whatever we want the resulting output to be. In machine translation it is the sentence in the other language for example.  We can compare the two with average cross entropy loss over each word predicted.  Finally we can update W with back propagation.

How do we see what is important?  We can look at the magnitudes of Z to see after the attention what words were most "attended" to.

This is a slightly simplified example as it only has one weight matrix and typically the inputs are embedded but I think it still highlights some of the necessary details concerning attention.

Here is a useful resource with visualizations for more information about [attention](https://jalammar.github.io/visualizing-neural-machine-translation-mechanics-of-seq2seq-models-with-attention/).
Here is another resource with visualizations for more about attention in transformers specifically [self-attention](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/).

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I do not understand how that "importance" is measured. Important for what?

That "importance" is measured by the dot product and adjusted by the cross-entropy loss.  Important for what?  The semantic similarity between the words.

> What exactly is the goal vector the weights in the self-attention algorithm are trained against?

The goal is dependent on the task and defined by the target in the training data.